# how to delay a function from happening until a time after load

Tags: jquery, load, delay

I want to show an element and hide an element at the same time, 2 seconds after the page has loaded, I know the below code is not right, but I am just using it to help understand the logic I am trying to achieve.

```
delay(2000).$('#customer_contact').hide().$('#customer_contact_edit_cont').show();
```

How could this logic best be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the syntax issues, the `delay()` function is intended to delay animations from happening which are scheduled to run on jQuery's `fx` queue.

If you want to delay an action from occurring outside of animation then you can use `setTimeout()`, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#customer_contact').hide();
  $('#customer_contact_edit_cont').show();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(
   function(){ 
     //Do something 
   }, 5000);
```

Here `5000` being the time in milliseconds. (`1 sec = 1000 ms`)